# Add second DNS to VM with Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, dns, iaas, azure-powershell

I'm currently rolling out an IaaS environment with 2 Domain controllers (both VM's too)
Setting the DNS statically in the OS adapter settings is not the way to go in Azure (reload will clear settings)

I'm setting the DNS settings through powershell, when I create the VM

$myDNS = New-AzureDNS -Name 'myDC01' -IPAddress a.b.c.d
.. 
New-AzureVM -serviceName $cloudservice -DnsSettings $myDNS -VNetName  $vnetname -waitforboot

this sets 1 DNS server in ipconfig, but is there a way to add an alternate (second) DNS setting too? this way I can put both DC's in an Availability Group and make sure DNS is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use netsh:

```
netsh interface ip add dns "Network Connection Name" a.b.c.d
netsh interface ip add dns "Network Connection Name" e.f.g.h
```

You can run these system commands from powershell by using `Invoke-Expression`

Answer (score 0):

```
$DC = read-host "Please enter a primary DNS"
$Internet = read-host "Please enter secondary DNS"
$dns = "$DC", "$Internet"
```

For powershell 4:

## I know this one is sloppy, but will get the work done.

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 -ServerAddresses ($DNS)
#I know this one is sloppy, but will get the work done.
```

For Powershell 1,2 and 3.

```
$Interface = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format T):Registering DNS $dns for $server" -ForegroundColor Green
$Interface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dns)
```

I plucked these off a script I wrote actually yesterday for a client that needed to set the DNS range for some-odd 200 Computers since the DC was failing.

If you are interested I can give you the whole script.
Point of the script is to run in a domain, and set every computer' DNS in the domain.